# moviepy add fade effect for each text in `SubtitlesClip()` object

Tags: python, video, moviepy, subtitle, video-editing

I've been trying to add subtitles to a video and it works fine but I wanted to add a fade effect to the subtitles, why ways I could do it?

The code I'm using

```py
generator = lambda txt: TextClip(txt, font='Font.otf', fontsize=18, color='white')
subtitles = SubtitlesClip('subs.srt', generator).set_start(1).subclip(19, 35)
video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, subs])
video.write_videofile("crop.mp4", fps=30, codec="libx264", audio=False, preset='veryfast')
```

yeah I could extract the text and do it but I don't know how to get the updated timestamps after doing `subtitle.set_start(1).subclip(19, 35)`